# Vue how to implement a retry button in error boundary component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to create a Vue error handling component following a similar pattern to the one documented [here](https://medium.com/@dillonchanis/handling-errors-in-vue-with-error-boundaries-91f6ead0093b).  It is basically a wrapper that uses the `errorCaptured` lifecycle hook to detect errors in its child components.  If an error is caught, it hides the content passed into its slot and shows an error message instead.  Pretty simple.  Something like this:

**ErrorBoundary.vue**

```
<template>
 <div>
   <slot v-if="!err"></slot>
   <h1 v-else>Oopsy</h1>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'errorBoundary',
  data(){
    return {err: false};
  },
  errorCaptured(err){
     this.err = true;
     console.log(err);
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem I have is that `errorCaptured` does not capture errors thrown in its own component's scope. For example, here nothing is caught and logged.

**ErrorThrower.vue**

```
<template>
 <div>Some content</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'errorThrower',
  created(){
     throw new Error();
  },
  errorCaptured(err){
     console.log(err);
  }
}
</script>
```

If the above example caught the error, then I could add a retry prop to the `ErrorBoundary` component and   accept the content as a slot.  Like this:

**ErrorThrower.vue**

```
<template>
  <ErrorBoundary :onRetry="loadContent">
    <div>Some content</div>
  </ErrorBoundary>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'errorThrower',
  created(){
     this.loadContent();
  },
  methods: {
    loadContent(){
      // make some call that fails
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, due to the slotted content being on the same scope as the `ErrorBoundary` component.

Whereas if `ErrorThrower` is a child compoment, `ErrorBoundary` will log the error and display a message, because now `ErrorThrower`'s error is caught by `errorCaptured`.

**SomeParent.vue**

```
<template>
 <error-boundary>
   <error-thrower/>
 </error-boundary>
</template>
```

How can I include a retry button in `ErrorBoundary`'s error message, that will retry some failed async operation if desired?  Ideally I want to pass in the callback for the error component to retry on error.

Comment: According to the documentation (https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorCaptured) - the `errorCaptured` hook is `Called when an error from any descendent component is captured`. So it does not capture the own component's errors by design. Perhaps you will need to use the global `config.errorHandler` ....

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Not sure how `errorHandler` would work.  I need to know where the error initiated so I can show the error message in the correct spot.  I could use a message bus or vuex to emit an ID the error component could look for.  The id would be passed in as a prop.  But I guess I was hoping to avoid requiring the consuming component to do anything.

Comment: You can use the global `config.errorHandler` without any of the `errorCaptured` hooks - since the `errorHandler` provides the component instance as its 2nd argument if you make all of your components to use a mixin with a method `retryOnError` then you can call the method on the failing component. I hope you get my point.

Comment: Thank you.  I think that would probably work.  Have to give it a try.